# Removing duplicates of a specific combination

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to remove some records that are duplicated from my data frame. But only duplicates of a specific combination.

For example, from this example `Id|Status` I would like to remove duplicates with status 'B'. That is, status 'A' can appear multiple times, but status 'B' can only appear once per 'Id'

```
1 A
1 A
1 A
1 A
2 A
2 A
1 B
2 B
2 B
```

It should result in:

```
1 A
1 A
1 A
2 A
2 A
1 B
2 B
```

Which would be the best way of doing it?

Test data:

```
 test <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2))
 test$status <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B", "B")
```

Comment: Just filter with your condition: `df1[ df1$Status != "B" | !duplicated(df1), ]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might do what you want. If you test for equality you could get problems when the  2nd column value is NA. `x == "B"` will be NA and then there will be an NA row in the result.

```
test <- read.table(text="1 A
 1 A
 1 A
 1 A
 2 A
 2 A
 1 B
 2 B
 2 B")
 test[ !( duplicated(test) & ( test[[2]] %in% "B")) , ]
#-------    
  V1 V2
1  1  A
2  1  A
3  1  A
4  1  A
5  2  A
6  2  A
7  1  B
8  2  B
```

Comment: I tried with `test[ !duplicated(test) & ( !test[[2]] %in% "B") , ]` using the test data I added and it didn't work :(

Comment: Right. Needed a bit of grouping. See if the edit is satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` you could do something like:

```
library(dplyr)
noDups <- "B"
test %>% group_by(status, id) %>% 
filter( !(status %in% noDups) | row_number()==1 )
```